# Receiving messages over bluetooth to raspberrypi

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I would like to receive the messages from my phone to raspberry over bluetooth

I have written the following code ,

```
import bluetooth

hostMACAddress = '18:9E:FC:A1:81:93' # The MAC address of my iphone
port = 3
backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
s.bind((hostMACAddress, port))
s.listen(backlog)
try:
    client, clientInfo = s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data:
            print(data)
            client.send(data) # Echo back to client
except: 
    print("Closing socket")
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

How can i receive the messages to my Raspberry when i run this code, i see no messages being received, my raspberry detects the MAC address of my iPhone but i would like to send some message and see if the bluetooth of raspberry can receive it

Kindly let me know what modifications i have to do in this code in order to achieve bluetooth connection

Comment: The code you posted is not iOS code. Is it Android or Raspberry Pi code? What language is it?

Comment: You can't make a legacy bluetooth connection to an iOS device.  You will need to use GATT over Bluetooth Low Energy with appropriate code on both the iOS device and Pi

Comment: @DuncanC , Its python code, Yes its Raspberry Pi code

Comment: @Paulw11, Could you please kindly cite some examples how to should i proceed, actually i would like to connect google glass to my Raspberry pi, but initially i am testing with my IOS device

Comment: Apple does not allow "regular" iOS developers to develop legacy BlueTooth apps. You have to qualify for and sign up for a peripheral licensing program for that. BLE, on the other hand, is open.

Comment: @DuncanC, I would like to connect my Bluetooth on Google glass with Raspberry Pi and transmit some messages. could you please let me know some examples how i could do that

Comment: Does Google Glass use BLE or legacy BlueTooth? I know that legacy Bluetooth is not available for iOS without a special license from Apple. I know exactly zero about Bluetooth on Google Glass or the Pi.

Comment: @DuncanC  Google glass uses legacy bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

I haven't completed building an app using Flutter but I have the server/client code ready using python.

***Server.py***

```
import socket
import os
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import pool
os.system('sudo python3 relay.py C') #runs relay program and setups up GPIO pins
hostMACAddress = 'B8:27:EB:A3:B6:EB' # The MAC address of a Bluetooth adapter on the server.
backlog = 4
port=3
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind((hostMACAddress,port))
s.listen(backlog)

def new_client(client):
    while 1:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data:
            n=data.decode("utf-8")
            if n == 'ON':
                os.system('sudo python3 relay.py ON')
            if n == 'OFF':
                os.system('sudo python3 relay.py OFF')
            if n == 'CLOSE':
                break
            client.send(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client, address = s.accept()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(new_client, (client, ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join
    print("Closing socket")
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

This is my server program running on raspberry pi.
I implemented multithreading to allow 4 active connections(sockets) at all time, since bluetooth is a little different than web socket programming I had to get creative to keep the application running after any client closes connection.
Basically if I get the message ON/OFF, it in turn runs another python program that turn the relay on or off, if I get CLOSE message, I terminate the thread.

***Client.py***

```
import bluetooth
bd_addr = 'B8:27:EB:A3:B6:EB'
port = 3
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr,port))
print("Connected")
while True:
    try:
        data = input()
        sock.send(data.encode())
        if data == 'CLOSE':
            break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sock.close()
```

This is my client program running on my computer.
**Notice** the address in both codes in the same(MAC Address of my raspberry pi), because raspberry pi need the address of the bluetooth adapter to use(in case some machines have multiple interfaces) and client needs server bluetooth MAC Address in order to initiate socket connection. You also need to port that you configured in raspbery pi to receive connection in my case 3.

Let me know if you need any additional information.
Have fun making an app that implements socket programming!